# What are the solutions for $a(n)$ and $b(n)$ when $a(n+1)=a(n)b(n)$ and $b(n+1)=a(n)+b(n)$?

Tags: real-analysis, recurrence-relations, recursive-algorithms

If you have the following recurrence relations :

$a(n+1)= a(n) b(n)$

$b(n+1)= a(n) + b(n) $

How do you find the form of $a(n)$ and $b(n)$ ? I suspect there isn't a closed form , but a infinit sum is good enough . Also what should the values $a(0)$ and $b(0)$, be so that the limit of $b(n)$ as n goes to infinity is 1 ?

Comment: One possible initial condition such that $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty}b(n) = 1$ is $a(0) = 0$ and $b(0) = 1$. Another is $a(0) = 1$ and $b(0) = 0$. There could be more.

Comment: If you let $c(0) = b(0), c(n) = a(n-1), n > 0$, then the recurrence becomes $c(n+1) = c(n)\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}c(i)$.  But this develops rather provocatively!  Even setting the two initial values equal, $c(0) = c(1)$, produces some interesting behavior.

Comment: $\lim_{n \to \infty} b(n) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=0}^n c(n) = 1$ when $c(0) = c(1) = k$ for $k$ somewhere near $0.298$, by numerical approach.  I'm not sure how much error is in my computations, though.

Comment: I don't know whether it helps: $a_{n+1}=a_n\cdot{b_n}$, so $b_n=\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$, and thus $\prod_{k=0}^{n}b_k=\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_0}$ Also, by considering $\frac{a_{n+2}}{a_{n+1}}=b_{n+1}=a_n+b_n=\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}+a_n$, so $a_n=\frac{a_{n+2}}{a_{n+1}}-\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}$, and we have $\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_k=\frac{a_{n+2}}{a_{n+1}}-\frac{a_1}{a_0}$.

Comment: @JimmyK4542 Your condition can be verified by the futhur calculation of my result. Let $n=2p-1$, so $\prod_{k=0}^{2p-1}b_k=\frac{a_{n}}{a_0}$. Assume ${b_n}$ is geometric series. Then take the GM. We have ${b_p}{b_{p-1})~(\frac{a_n}{a_0})^{1/p}=(\frac{a_n}{a_0})^{\frac2{n+1}}$. When $n\to\infty$, ${b_p}{b_{p-1}}=1$

Answer (score 2):

A continuous version of these equations would be
$$\frac{d}{dt}\ln a(t)=\ln b(t)\\
\frac{d}{dt}b(t)=a(t)\\
\ddot{b}=\dot{b}\ln b\\
\dot{b}=b\ln b-b+C\\
t=\int\frac{db}{b\ln b-b+C}$$
Since $t\to\infty$ when $b\to1$, we need $C=1$.  The leading terms near $b=1$ are
$$t=\int \frac2{(b-1)^2}+\frac2{3(b-1)}-\frac19+\frac{7(b-1)}{135}+...db$$
so to leading order $t=2/(1-b)$, or $b\approx1-2/t$.  Then $a=db/dt\approx2/t^2$.
I don't know how much of that carries over to the discrete case.
EDIT:
PRELIM
$$\frac1{(n+1)^2}=\frac1{n^2}(1+\frac1n)^{-2}$$
By geometric series,
$$(1+\frac1n)^{-1}=1-\frac1n+\frac1{n^2}-\frac1{n^3}+\cdots$$
If you multiply that series by itself, term by term, you get
$$(1+\frac1n)^{-2}=1-\frac2n+\frac3{n^2}-\frac4{n^3}+\cdots\\
\frac1{(n+1)^2}=\frac1{n^2}-\frac2{n^3}+\frac3{n^4}-\cdots$$
Also, a similar thing for logs base e, because $1+1/n$ is near $1$, is
$$\ln(1+\frac1n)=\frac1n-\frac1{2n^2}+\frac1{3n^3}-\cdots$$
I can't explain that without calculus, but you can check $\ln1.01$ and $\ln0.99$.
NOW
It seems that the following leading-order works.  The idea is
$$a(n)=f_0(n)+f_1(n)+...\\b(n)=g_0(n)+g_1(n)+...$$
where $f_0$ and $g_0$ are known, and $f_1$ and $g_1$ are small corrections.
Since $f_0(n)=2/n^2$, we have $f_0(n+1)\approx 2/n^2-4/n^3+...$. Find a similar expression for $g_0(n+1)$.  Put them into $a(n+1)=a(n)b(n)$ and $b(n+1)=a(n)+b(n)$, and suppose $f_1(n+1)\approx f_1(n)$ and $g_1(n+1)\approx g_1(n)$.  Solve for $f_1$ and $g_1$.  If you assume $f_1$ is $O(n^{-3})$ and $g_1$ is $O(n^{-2})$  you get cancellation, with terms left over from $f_0$ and $g_0$.  So you need $f_1=O(n^{-3}\ln n)$ and $f_2=O(n^{-3})$.  Now $f_1(n+1)$ has a term $O(n^{-4})$  which you can match with the one from $f_0$.

:
$$a(n)=\frac2{n^2}+\frac2{3n^3}(1-8\ln n)+...\\
b(n)=1-\frac2n+\frac{8\ln n}{3n^2}- \frac{32}{9n^3}\left(\ln^2n-\ln n+1/2\right)+...$$

Comment: Hi, sorry if this is an old post and you forgotten about it. May I know how do you get the a(n) and b(n) step by step? I am keen to learn about it as your formula yield good accuracy.

Comment: @MaximusSu I've edited it a bit.  I think it's called 'asymptotic analysis' when it's not just a Taylor series.

Comment: Hi sir, if you add f0(n)=2/n2  + f1=O(n−2lnn)  which is equal to a(n), can you show the small summation steps instead of just showing final answer of a(n)? It's quite hard for me to understand as my knowledge in maths is still high school :))

Comment: Hi sir, sorry to bother u again. How do you get the a(n) to be 2/3n^3 (1-8In(n)) +...  ?

Comment: If a(n+1)=a(n)b(n)  and b(n+1)=a(n)+9 b(n)  condition is used, I am curious, does your method work as well?

Comment: I forget the details, but once you have $f1$, then you look at even smaller correction terms with $f_0+f_1+f_2$, and solve for $f_2$.

Comment: Normally yes.  The fixed point is $a_n=-8,b_n=1$.  But this time, small offsets will grow, by a factor of about $5+\sqrt8$ at each step.  So I don't think there is a stable solution in this xase.