# Quadratic Equation Recurrence?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, recurrence-relations, generating-functions, quadratics

So I was playing around with the following:

Let $f_0(x) = x^2 - bx + c$.

If $f_n(x)$ has roots $p$ and $q$ with $p > q$, then let $f_{n+1}(x) = x^2 - px + q$.

The recurrence relation is rather simple: if we let $f_n(x) = x^2 - b_nx + c_n$, then $b_{n+1} + c_{n+1} = b_n$ and $b_{n+1}c_{n+1} = c_n$.

I wrote a program to iteratively find these quadratics until the discriminant is less than zero: in the case they do not terminate, the values of $b_n$ and $c_n$ always seem to converge such that $c_n = 0$. However, I couldn't figure out what $b_n$ converges to by inspection. Anyone has any ideas on how this works? I couldn't solve the recurrence relation very easily.

Here is the code: http://ideone.com/42sqow. For example, for $b_0 = 5$ and $c_0 = 1$, $b_n$ and $c_n$ converge to $4.7355610384$ and $0$, respectively.

Comment: I dont know (I only can assume a lot of radicals) but this is a beautiful problem ! May be, you could add to the post (for any value of $p,q$ of your choice) a plot of the parameters as functions of $n$. Thanks !

Comment: I don't have the time to make a graph right now, but I added a bit more information. :D

Comment: For largish $b>c$, it seems that $(b,c)$ ends up near $b-(c/b)$

Comment: Hmm, interesting. It does seem to be a little less than $b$, but not really $b - (c/b)$.

Comment: A better estimate seems to be $(b,ab)\to b-a-(a^2+a)/b-(2a^3+2a^2+a)/b^2-(5a^4+5a^3+4a^2+a)/b^3-(14a^5+14a^4+14a^3+6a^2+a)/b^4-(42a^6+42a^5+48a^4+28a^3+9a^2+a)/b^5$

Comment: The boundary for ending with complex numbers may have the equation $y=f(x)$ where $f(x+f(x))=xf(x)$.  An approximate solution for large $x$ would be $f(x)\approx x^{\phi}$, but doesn't work well for small $x$

Comment: @Zach466920  I started with $(b,ba)$, so for $(5,1)$ you have $b=5,a=1/5$

Comment: @Michael how did you get that estimate? it definitely seems correct, especially with small values of $a$.

Comment: I put it through Maple.  I think that each iteration of the procedure provides one more term in the Taylor series because $q$ shrinks by a factor close to $b$ at each stage.  Ten iterations was too much for Maple to handle, but half a dozen iterations was fine.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Is there any way to actually/analytically prove this?

Comment: A function with $f(x+f(x))=xf(x)$ (see my earlier comment) is $f(1+x)=0(x<0)$ and $f(1+x)=\frac12x^2-\frac16x^3+...(x>0)$

Comment: Sorry for all the questions, but I'm not exactly sure how that functional equation is relevant. :/

Comment: This feels _very_ close to the [Arithmetic-Geometric mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic%E2%80%93geometric_mean), but I don't see any way of reducing one recurrence to the other...

Comment: @Steven Stadnicki The AGM preserves the units, and this procedure does not (which does make it somewhat unnatural for my taste).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a start, I may figure some more things out and post here.

Take the two recurrence relations.
$$(1) \quad b_{n+1}+c_{n+1}=b_{n}$$
and
$$(2) \quad b_{n+1} \cdot c_{n+1}=c_{n}$$

Assume that both $b$ and $c$ converge as the number of iterations tends to infinity. This means that $b_{n+1}=b_{n}$ and $c_{n+1}=c_{n}$. Using this in the system of equations, we get.

$$b+c=b$$
$$\Rightarrow c=0$$
and
$$b \cdot c=c$$
$$\Rightarrow b=k$$
Where $k$ is a constant. This is important because it means that I have half of the answer to this problem. $b$ equals something, but we now know that $c=0$ as the number of iterations approaches infinity. Of course, I assume that system of difference equations converges, but I don't think that's too big of an assumption to yield the above analysis invalid.

**Perturbation Theory**

I doubt this problem has an exact solution, however, given that we know the solution for $c_0=0$ and $b_0=b$ we can perturb $c_0$ to get a better estimate. Firstly, (1) and (2) are equivalent to

$$(3) \quad b_{n+1}={{b_n+\sqrt{{b_n}^2-4 \cdot c_n}} \over 2}$$
and
$$(4) \quad c_{n+1}={{b_n-\sqrt{{b_n}^2-4 \cdot c_n}} \over 2}$$

Since we're assuming $c_0$ is small, at least for now, we can take (3) as an approximation for $b_{\infty}$...

For $b_0=5$ $c_0=x$, the graph looks like this...

[image: Graph Approximation]

And for $c_0=1$ we get $b_{\infty} \sim 4.79...$. Not bad for a first approximation. You can keep making better approximations, but the graph displayed above, is very representative of the general behavior. Also, if you expand the above out in series form, and keep iterating, the series should converge to the correct perturbation series. For instance, for the above first iteration, the first two terms for the Taylor expansion are
$$b-{c \over b}$$
So these are most likely the first two terms of the perturbation series for the solution.

Let's look at the second convergent for $b_{\infty}$. I've already taken the liberty of simplifying the expression.
$$b_{\infty} \sim b_2={{\sqrt{2 \cdot \left((b+4) \cdot \sqrt{b^2-4 \cdot c}+b^2-4 \cdot b-2 \cdot c \right)}+\sqrt{b^2-4 \cdot c}+b} \over 4}$$

As long as b is positive, the perturbation series for $b_{\infty}$ is now approximated by.

$$b_{\infty} \sim b-{c \over b}-{c \over {b^2}}-{{c^2} \over {b^3}}-{{2 \cdot c^2} \over {b^4}}-O(c^3)$$

For $b=5$ and $a=1$ we'll get $4.747... \ $ as an approximation to $b_{\infty}$, that's only about a $0.24$% error. I should also stress that this series expansion for $b_2$ contains terms from $b_1$. Thus, we can intuitively expect the series for $b_n$ to converge to the series for $b_{\infty}$ as n approaches infinity. In addition, most other answers miss the fact that you need a lot series terms to get a good estimate for the recursion. However, I've only used two iterations so far. Sometimes the easiest way to approximate something is just by using what's already given to you.

Comment: Thanks Zach, that's a step in the right direction. Any ideas on finding the value of $b$?

Comment: @Ashkay I gave start for addressing that problem...of course no solution yet.

Comment: @Ashkay Thanks for the bounty!

Comment: No problem. :D So you don't think there's any explicit formula or series to find the limit, its only something that can be found recursively?

Comment: @Ashkay I'm about 95% sure at this point that there is no explicit formula. Compare this with $z_{n+1}=(z_{n})^2+c$ which also has no explicit solution for $c \not =0$. The actual boundary of convergence is fractal called the Mandelbrot Set, sorry if you already knew that :) So you might want to look into convergence in the complex case, you might get some interesting fractals. Complexity from simplicity is both really annoying and also kind of beautiful...

Answer (score 1):

Last month there was a similar problem, but with time in the opposite direction.
[What are the solutions for $a(n)$ and $b(n)$ when $a(n+1)=a(n)b(n)$ and $b(n+1)=a(n)+b(n)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1288143/what-are-the-solutions-for-an-and-bn-when-an1-anbn-and-bn1)
EDIT: Boundary of the points that end up complex:
Let $A$ be the region bounded by the curves $(x,y)=(t,t)$ and $(x,y)=(2t,t^2)$.  Those points all end up complex in the next iteration.
Let $B$ be the region bounded by the curves $(x,y)=(2t,t^2)$ and $(x,y)=(2t+t^2,2t^3)$.  Those points all end up in Region A, and then complex in the following iteration.
Region C is one step back in time again, and ends up complex in three steps.  Repeat it to get a region of starting points that end up complex.  OP noted that the backward iteration replaces $(x,y)$ with $(x+y,xy)$.  If these backward iterations of the line between $(0,0)$ and $(4,4)$ settle down to a curve $y=f(x)$, (and it looks like they do), then $(x,f(x))$ goes to $(x+f(x),xf(x))$, so $f(x+f(x))=xf(x)$.
I observed that the limit curve is $y=0$ for $x\leq a$, and then $f(a+z)\approx Kz^n$ to leading order for small $z>0$, for some $K$ and $n$.  Then to leading order, 
$$f(x+f(x))\approx xf(x)\\
f(a+z+Kz^n)\approx (a+z)(Kz^n)\\
K(z+Kz^n)^n\approx aKz^n+Kz^{n+1}\\
Kz^n(1+Kz^{n-1})^n\approx aKz^n+Kz^{n+1}\\
(1+Kz^{n-1})^n\approx a+z\\
a=1,n=2,K=1/2\\
f(1+z)\approx \frac12z^2$$
So $(p,q)=(1.1,0.005)$ is near the edge.  Assuming $f$ has a Taylor series, Maple tells me it is 
$$f(1+z)\approx\frac{z^2}2-\frac{z^3}{12}+\frac{z^4}{24} -\frac{7z^5}{240} +\frac{103z^6}{4320}...$$
The function $f(x+f(x))=xf(x)$ seems to cut $x=f(x)$ at around $x\approx4.4$, so the procedure gives real answers if $p$ is greater than that.
Other solutions of the equation are $n=1,K=a-1$, for which $$(x,y)\approx(a+t,a+(a-1)t+t^2/(a+1)+...)$$

Comment: As with integration, inverting a problem can make the inverted problem solvable, but sometimes both the original and inversion are unsolvable.

Comment: Hmm, interesting, I'll work with it for a bit. Can that be easily applied to the backwards case?

Comment: Also, is there a way to solve this with generating functions?

Answer (score 1):

This is just another approach to the problem, not sure if it gets anywhere.

If the limit of $b_n$ is $f(b,c)$, then we have (in an appropriate range)
$$
f(b+c,bc)=f(b,c).
$$
Assuming that $c$ is small, it is plausible that this $f$ will be given by a convergent power series in $c$, so (since $f(b,0)=b$)
$$
f(b,c) = b + \sum_{k>0} a_k(b)c^k.
$$
Then the above functional equation becomes
$$
b+c+\sum_{k>0}a_k(b+c)b^kc^k=b+\sum_{k>0}a_k(b)c^k.
$$
In particular, assuming various convergences, we get:
$$
1+a_1(b)b=a_1(b)
$$
so $a_1(b) = \frac 1{1-b}$. Then looking at the coefficients by $c^2$ one gets,
by expanding $a_1(b+c)=\frac 1{1-b-c}$ around $c=0$ (if I am not mistaken):
$$\frac b{(1-b)^2} + a_2(b)b^2=a_2(b)
$$
and
$$
a_2(b)=\frac{b}{(1-b)^2(1-b^2)}.
$$
This can be continued, but I don't know if there will be a nice formula for 
the rational function $a_k(b)$. Perhaps, someone can try a few more steps and search for a pattern.

P.S. The second order approximation for $f(5,1)$ is
$$
5+\frac 1{1-5} + \frac{5}{(1-5)^2(1-5^2)} = 4.736979166\ldots
$$
which is reasonably close to the correct value.

Comment: No offense to your answer, but it seems your approximating one difference equation with another...

Comment: @Zach466920 If there is by some miracle a closed formula for $a_k(b)$ (unlikely) then there would be a series formula for the limit.

Comment: Of course, but what if this hypothetical series is defined recursively?

Comment: You can calculate $a_3(b)$ by looking at the coefficients by $c^3$, then calculate $a_4(b)$, etc. Then $f(b,c)=b+a_1(b)c+a_2(b)c^2+...$.

Comment: But in your very own answer you say "by expanding $a_1$ around $c=0$ (we get) $a_2={{b} \over {(1-b)^2 \cdot (1-b^2)}}$" So this formula *is* recursive since you calculate $a_{n+1}$ by using information about $a_n$. If you wrote out the recursion formula for $a_k$ we might be able to solve it, also maybe you could expand your discussion of "assuming various convergents, we get..."

Comment: The recursion for $a_{n+1}$ uses all previous $a_k$...

Comment: That was entailed in what I just said. $a_{n}$ relies on $a_{n-1}$ and so on...