# Taylor series of 1/( xlog(x)-x )

Tags: integration, discrete-mathematics, derivatives, taylor-expansion

[image]

How to convert 1/(bIn(b)-b+C)? I have tried using Wolfram Taylor Series to evaluate it, the calculator does not give any answer.

I got this info from [What are the solutions for $a(n)$ and $b(n)$ when $a(n+1)=a(n)b(n)$ and $b(n+1)=a(n)+b(n)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1288143/what-are-the-solutions-for-an-and-bn-when-an1-anbn-and-bn1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the expansion of
$$
\frac{1}{(1+h)\ln(1+h)-(1+h)+1}=\frac1{(1+h)(h-\frac12h^2+\frac13h^3-\frac14h^4+...)-h}
\\=\frac1{h^2+(1+h)(-\frac12h^2+\frac13h^3-\frac14h^4+...)}
$$
in a Laurent power series in $h$. Further expansion in the denominator gives
$$
=\frac1{h^2}·\frac1{\frac12-\frac1{2·3}h+\frac1{3·4}h^2-\frac1{4·5}h^3+...}
=\frac2{h^2}·\frac1{1-\frac13h+\frac16h^2-\frac1{10}h^3+...}
$$
It remains to carry out the power series division.